# Example of a scenario written in Gherkin Pirate

Tags: cucumber, specflow, gherkin

From what I can see, Gherkin supports many different languages including Pirate

Could someone list an example of the keywords in pirate and what a scenario may sound like or know of a site that has some example listed?

Comment: Why of why do you want to write the scenario in Pirate?

Comment: Arrgh, cause me writing pirate applications blimey ;-)

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To get a full list of keywords, simply run `cucumber --i18n en-pirate`

Currently this returns:

```
  | feature          | "Ahoy matey!"            |
  | background       | "Yo-ho-ho"               |
  | scenario         | "Heave to"               |
  | scenario_outline | "Shiver me timbers"      |
  | examples         | "Dead men tell no tales" |
  | given            | "* ", "Gangway! "        |
  | when             | "* ", "Blimey! "         |
  | then             | "* ", "Let go and haul " |
  | and              | "* ", "Aye "             |
  | but              | "* ", "Avast! "          |
  | given (code)     | "Gangway"                |
  | when (code)      | "Blimey"                 |
  | then (code)      | "Letgoandhaul"           |
  | and (code)       | "Aye"                    |
  | but (code)       | "Avast"                  |
```

Also try `cucumber --i18n help` to see all other possible languages (including Scouse and Australian...)

Comment: voting this one up on talk like a pirate day in the hope people might test like a pirate as well.